# SQL Retrieve data from first table based on search criteria in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i Have 2 tables i want to get data from the first table based on where condition applied on the second table.

```
PHARMASTOCK(1)      Pharma Products(2)
ID                  ProductID   
ProductID           GenericName 
TradeName           TradeName   
MRP                 Supplier    
Rate                Manufacturer    
Stock               PurchasePTR 
Batch               UnitRate    
Expiry              MRP 
StockSection
```

This is the SQL stored procedure that i have written but it is not working
as expected!

```
@StockSupplier varchar(50), @StockManufacturer Varchar(50)
AS


SELECT  PharmaStock.ProductID,PharmaStock.TradeName,PharmaStock.MRP,Rate,Batch,Expiry,StockSection,Stock,Supplier,Manufacturer 
from PharmaStock 
    Full JOIN PharmaProducts ON PharmaStock.ProductID = PharmaProducts.ProductID 
where Supplier  like + @StockSupplier + '%' and Manufacturer  like + @StockManufacturer + '%'
order by Manufacturer asc
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Your FULL OUTER JOIN returns RIGHT OUTER JOIN result. Move the WHERE clause conditions to the ON clause to get true FULL OUTER JOIN result.

Comment: What do you expect? What is the result of your query? What is wrong on the result? Can you give some example data?

Comment: @jarlh    MS SQL Server

Comment: @heiwil The query does not return any results !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT  PharmaStock.ProductID, 
PharmaStock.TradeName, 
PharmaStock.MRP, 
PharmaStock.Rate, 
PharmaStock.Batch, 
PharmaStock.Expiry, 
PharmaStock.StockSection, 
PharmaProducts.Supplier, 
PharmaProducts.Manufacturer  
FROM PharmaStock 
        INNER JOIN  PharmaProducts ON PharmaStock.ProductID = PharmaProducts.ProductID WHERE PharmaProducts.Supplier  LIKE  '%%' and PharmaProducts.Manufacturer  LIKE  '%%' 
ORDER BY PharmaProducts.Manufacturer asc
```

pass strings for supplier and Manufacturer to further filter join result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  PS.ProductID,PS.TradeName,PS.MRP,PS.Rate,PS.Batch,PS.Expiry,PS.StockSection,PS.Stock,PP.Supplier,PP.Manufacturer 
    from PharmaStock PS
        inner JOIN PharmaProducts PP ON PS.ProductID = PP.ProductID 
    where Supplier  like CONCAT(@StockSupplier , '%') and Manufacturer  like CONCAT(@StockManufacturer ,'%') order by Manufacturer asc
```

The concatenate function is changed in the query and then the plus symbol(after like needs to be removed).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  PharmaStock.ProductID,PharmaStock.TradeName,PharmaStock.MRP,Rate,Batch,Expiry,StockSection,Stock,Supplier,Manufacturer 
from PharmaStock 
INNER JOIN PharmaProducts ON PharmaStock.ProductID = PharmaProducts.ProductID 
where Supplier  like  @StockSupplier + '%' and Manufacturer  like  @StockManufacturer + '%'
order by Manufacturer asc
```